# Android tv testing onReceivedError

Tags: android, android-tv

I use a web view in my Android TV app and have handlers attached to it like:

```
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
        }
    });
```

How would I go about testing this?

Answer (score 0):

onReceivedError:

> This method was deprecated in API level 23.

you should to use

```
void onReceivedError (WebView view, 
                WebResourceRequest request, 
                WebResourceError error)
```

[onReceivedError in android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedError(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest,%20android.webkit.WebResourceError))

If you want to test the error case, try to connect a unknown web page, for example: http://google.com/404

run this code after creating and initializing the webview object

```
webView.loadUrl("http://google.com/404");
```

I hope this code will trigger the onReceivedError function

Comment: Hey thanks, I meant unit test. As in how can I get hold of the callback reference to then call it in a test and assert that my error page was loaded?